# BizTalk deployment - Binding Files not well imported into custom pipeline component

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-deployment, custom-pipeline-component

When I deploy my applications I notice a very strange behaviour – Not all binding files are imported as they should be while others are.

I'm using a custom pipeline component that promotes a set of properties to the context, some are defined at in the pipeline itself while others are defined in the BTS Admin console so we can define them in the binding files.

```
<ReceivePipelineData>&lt;Root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" … Components&gt;&lt;Component Name="I.MMA.COMPONENT"&gt;&lt;Properties &gt;&lt;Customer vt="8"&gt;CUSTOMER_NAME&lt;/Customer&gt;&lt; … etc.
```

This works fine for some of our applications, they are being well deployed and our values that are configured in the binding file are visible in the admin portal while other applications don’t show the same information and the strange part is that, when we generate the binding files for the failing applications, the values are in the binding file but not visible nor used by BTS.

I have this behavior on different machines, anybody got an idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently moved my pipeline component from one stage to another while I didn't update the **Stage CategoryId** and the values were ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar and fixed it by manually re-entering the pipeline settings in the admin console. I suspect that if the binding file settings are not exactly what the console expects for the pipeline then it doesn't display them. So try re-entering the settings for the affected ports and update your binding files from that.

Comment: Problem was that I didn't update my Stage CategoryId as noted below!